# How to escape characters inside of a parameter in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, escaping

This is a simplified version of my function:

```
function DetectLocalUser($localGroup, $members)
{
    $result = net localgroup "$localGroup"
    #$members=  $members.Replace("\","\\")

    if ($result -match $members)
    {
        return $true
    }
    else
    {
        return $false
    }
}
```

To invoke the function I use this example (Typical values I am going to receive):

```
DETECTLocalUser "test" "iis apppool\userapi"
```

**The parameters are not controlled by me**. If they were I would escape directly the second parameter *"iis apppool\\userapi"*

On execution I have a problem with the \ in the parameter. The exact error is:

> parsing "iis apppool\icisapi" - Unrecognized escape sequence \i. At
>   C:\k\a.ps1:6 char:9
>   +     if ($result -match $members)
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

I found a workaround by adding `#$members=  $members.Replace("\","\\")` fixes the problem but I am not sure if is the best option.

**Is my workaroud acceptable or is there a better way of escaping $members parameter?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```powershell
[RegEx]::Escape($members)
```

That will ensure that characters in strings get interpreted as literals and not as part of the RegEx.

To explain further, the `-match` operator is doing a regular expression match, so the string you pass to it is interpreted as a regular expression.

Backslash happens to be the escape character in a regular expression, so that's where your issue is. Using `[RegEx]::Escape()` ensures that other characters won't be interpreted, such as `[`,`]`,`.`,`+`,`(`,`)`,`^`,`$`,`?`,`*`, etc.

Comment: I tested it and it works perfectly. It is better than my workaround because it escapes all special characters and I don't need to recode that logic myself. TA!